# Can't import pyttsx in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu Linux 16

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyttsx

I'm trying to use pyttsx on Ubuntu Linux (64 bit, PC) with Python 2.7. I've successfully used pip to install the package

```
$sudo -H pip install pyttsx
$pip list
...
pyttsx (1.1)
...
```

When I try to import it the import call fails

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyttsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyttsx
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this. When I search for the question here on Stack Overflow I encounter one other instance about the same error message on a Raspberry Pi. But the solution mentioned there doesn't bring resolution on my PC so I don't think it is not related.

Any ideal what I am missing that is preventing the import from being successful?

Comment: Please make sure, that the pip is referring to the right python binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your pip is tied to your python installation by checking both path's.

In Pip check:

```
`pip --version` 
 pip 9.0.1 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Later in python:

```
import sys
print sys.executable
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Comment: Try doing `pip2 install pyttsx`. All the pip executables should be in `/usr/local/bin` and there are pips for all the versions of your python versions.

Answer (score 1):

1. run which pip, which python, make sure they are same suite
2. when run pip install, it should feedback the package is installed in which path
3. run this code in python

`import sys
for i in sys.path:
    print i`

to check if your syspath including that path or not.